# Security increase by use of uncommon IPs?

Tags: ip

I read here: https://www.privux.de/raspberry-netzwerk-einrichten/ about an implicit increase in security by using "uncommon" IPs in your home's LAN. That means not using 192.168.0.1, but 172.26.47.240 for example.

I think, if the attacker is already in my LAN, this method would not help me. If he is not in my LAN he cannot see the IPs anyway.

Maybe it is meant to make IP-Spoofing more "difficult"?

Can you explain what the increase of security is by using "uncommon" IPs?

For me it looks like "security by obscurity".

Comment: Apart from horrible grammar errors in your source: the author seems like he didn't really understand the RFC and doesn't explain his rationale. That was a horrible read.

Comment: Second that. Ignore this source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm focusing on using non-reserved IPs, because using the reserved ones, even the big ranges, is still easily feasible to enumerate. Your source leaves out any explanation for his reasoning and you are correct; this only helps if your network is already breached and then only insignificantly.
What your source is trying (and failing to achieve) is called network segregation - which is a good way of hindering lateral movement in networks.

Now: why even using all of the address space is a bad idea:

So, while using IP addresses that are not reserved for private use does in fact increase security (and in fact by obscurity), it is highly discouraged. If everything is configured correctly, this at least let's you run into problems when an IP you are trying to connect to over the WAN is routed in the LAN, because it's present there, too.

This increases security marginally by hiding a few local IPs not in the tiny space of reserved private IP ranges but all of the IP address space. But this only works if the machines you are hiding do not advertise services, do not respond to ICMP, ARP or DHCP requests or the like and you are using a switched network.

So there is a tiny chance that you are making lateral movement within your network harder for an adversary, simply by obscurity.

While security by obscurity is not considered secure, it at least adds a tiny bit of security to the overall security of the system; marginally so.

Additionally, be aware that using non-reserved IP addresses internally is not RFC-conform.